# Excel formula to Javascript, working but inconsistent

Tags: javascript, excel

Having problems getting consistent results, hoping for some pointers tried solving this myself hit a wall

Excel Formula:

```
=IF(C15=""," ",IF(D15="O"(((ROUNDUP(((C15+0.625)/(6.25-0.5)),0)*6.25))+4.125+0.5),IF(D15="t",C15,"ERROR")))
```

`C15= 100.00` logical test..

`D15="O"` second logical test,verifies that 100.00 can be expanded to predetermined result for that number...
`if D15="t"` for trapped it stays at `100.00`....
I can replace the logical test with "if else" later on, still learning

```
     <html>
       <head>
       <title>Excel Formula to JavaScript</title>
       </head>
         <body>
         <script type="text/javascript">

         var num1 = 170.00;
         var acc1 = (num1 + 0.625)/(6.25-0.50); 
         var acc2 = Math.round((acc1 * 10) / 10) * 6.25 + (4.125 + 0.50); 
         document.write(acc2).toFixed(3);

         </script>

         <div>
         <br>
         num1= 30.00 result should be 42.125".... incorrect result!
         <br>
         <br>
         num1= 40.00 result should be 54.625".... incorrect result!
         <br>
         <br>
         num1= 57.00 result should be 73.365".... incorrect result!
         <br>
         <br>
         num1= 85.00 result should be 98.375"... result correct
         <br>
         <br>
         when num1= 100.00 result should be 117.125"... result correct
         <br>
         <br>
         seems any input under 77 result will be incorrect 
         </div>
         </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your excel equation you are rounding **UP**.  So when `C15` is `30`, `acc1` is `5.326087` and excel roundup brings this to `6`.  Javascript `Math.Round(5.326087)` is rounding to the nearest whole so it's result is `5`.  This is enough to throw off your final result.

---

You can change excel to simply `Round` instead of `RoundUp` or you can change your javascript to `Math.ceil((acc1 * 10) / 10)`

---

Don't forget the comma after `IF(D15="O",`

Comment: Nice happy happy, math.ceil solution worked tested perfect every time! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert Excel spreadsheet to Javascript you can use the OpenSource library formula.js, developped by Stoic, which implements most of Excel functions

It's here : http://stoic.com/formula/

Otherwise I'm working on an online software that converts OpenDocument Calc into HTML+JS instantly. There is demo version that works for spreadsheet with less than 10 formulas.

It's here : http://appizy.com

Good luck on your project.

BR,
Nicolas